# Getting list of installed apps (NOT packages)

Tags: c++, application, qt

How can I get list of installed apps (based at files in /usr/share/applications/) without writing own parser? I need just app name, path to app icon and path to launch app.

I'm using C++ with Qt libraries. Of course, you can write me shell command or something else like it.

Comment: What do you mean by application? Which distribution?

Comment: @Matteo by 'application' i mean everything that is displayed in dash, Start menu or smth like this.

Comment: The parser it not hard to write, all entries use the "A[LANG]=B" form, you only need to combine QDir and QFile and little regex

Comment: @warl0ck Already wrote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty shell script that might help you. Adjust the output format to something that's easy to parse for you. Finding the right icon could use some improvement to select the highest resolution image. Maybe there's a better way to get the optimal icon using `gconftool` or something, I don't know.

```
#!/bin/sh

icon_basedir1=/usr/share/icons/gnome
icon_basedir2=/usr/share/icons/hicolor
icon_basedir3=/usr/share/pixmaps
icon_basedir4=/usr/share/app-install/icons

error() {
    echo $*
    exit 1
}

is_icon() {
    test -f "$1" && icon_path="$1" && return 0
    icon_path=$(find $2 -name $1.png | sort -r | head -n 1)
    test -f "$icon_path" && return 0
}

find_icon() {
    test "$icon_filename" || return
    is_icon $icon_filename $icon_basedir1 && return
    is_icon $icon_filename $icon_basedir2 && return
    is_icon $icon_filename $icon_basedir3 && return
    is_icon $icon_filename $icon_basedir4 && return
}

find_name() {
    test "$fullname" && name=$fullname && return 0
    test "$genericname" && name=$genericname && return 0
}

find /usr/share/applications -type f -name \*.desktop | while read file; do
    icon_filename=$(cat $file | grep ^Icon= | sed -ne 's/^.*=//' -e '1 p')
    find_icon
    executable_name=$(cat $file | grep ^Exec= | sed -ne 's/^.*=//' -e 's/ .*//' -e '1 p')
    fullname=$(cat $file | grep FullName.en_ | sed -ne 's/^.*=//' -e '1 p')
    genericname=$(cat $file | grep GenericName.en_ | sed -ne 's/^.*=//' -e '1 p')
    name=$(cat $file | grep -i Name | sed -ne 's/^.*=//' -e '1 p')
    find_name
    echo app_file=$file
    echo name=$name
    echo executable=$(which $executable_name || echo $executable_name)
    echo icon=$icon_path
    echo
done
```

Comment: You are a jewel among men, I have so much respect for you. You are just amazing my man.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `/usr/share/applications/` is <del>Gnome</del> windows manager specific and does not contain an entry for every application on your system (BTW you should define what do you mean by application).

In any case you can just list the entries in the directory

Comment: He did define what an application is for him, a program that has an entry in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `ls`?

Comment: Exactly, hence my comment. It seems strange that he is just asking how to list the files in a directory.

Comment: @jipple, not file list in directory, but App name (like Chrome), path to icon and path to running file (like /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome). It's written in .desktop files in /usr/share/applications/ directory.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Gnome-specific? E.g. I have kde4 subdirectory in /usr/share/applications/ with .desktop files for kde apps.